# Checking null values in dataset of multiple columns in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-cleaning

My dataset has more than 100 columns. I want to check the null values in the dataset. I used the following code.

**Code**

```
for col in train.columns:
    if (train[col].isnull().sum()==0):
        print(train[col])
```

I didn't get the answer I'm looking.

Comment: What is your desierd output? Do you whant to count them?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a great pacakage named [missingno](https://github.com/ResidentMario/missingno). You may want to check the repo.

Usage

```
import missingno as msno
msno.matrix(train) # Assuming train is a dataframe like.
```